# Where can I get a list of the "ambient properties" provided by NLog?

Tags: c#, .net, logging, nlog

In addition to layout renderers, NLog has "ambient properties" that are mentioned in some documentation pages (for example, `padding` in https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Pad-Layout-Renderer).

Is there a place where I can get a list of all the ambient properties available? I would like to use them where I can, as they are often easier to read than their equivalent layout renderer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All layout renderers could be found [here](https://nlog-project.org/config/?tab=layout-renderers), but there **isn't** a filter if it has ambient properties.

So for now only searching for `AmbientProperty` in code is the solution: [click](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/search?q=ambientproperty&type=)